# Setting java locale settings

Tags: java, locale

When I use the default java locale on my linux machine it comes out with the US locale settings, where do I change this so that it comes out with the correct locale?

Comment: Locale.getavailablelocale() method is not returning en_MY, why so? it returns 155 locales

Comment: @kekan : Try Locale.getDefault();

Comment: Beware of [Java 7 default locale changes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7107972/java-7-default-locale).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how do I set the default locale for my JVM?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8809098/how-do-i-set-the-default-locale-for-my-jvm)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I believe java gleans this from the environment variables in which it was launched, so you'll need to make sure your LANG and LC_* environment variables are set appropriately.

The locale [manpage](http://linux.die.net/man/1/locale) has full info on said environment variables.

Comment: What are the LC_* environment variables ?

Comment: If your program formats numbers, you probably want to set LC_ALL. See my answer below.

Comment: Be aware that this is incomplete. I'm running macOS Sierra and have LANG as well as LC_ALL set as "en_US.UTF8". However, for some reason Java comes up with `user.language=en`, `user.country=US` and `user.country.format=DE`.

Answer (score 51):

With the `user.language`, `user.country` and `user.variant` properties.

Example:

`java -Duser.language=th -Duser.country=TH -Duser.variant=TH SomeClass`

Comment: This will work, but it's safer and more future-proof to set the environment and let the JRE figure out the correct values for these.

Comment: The problem is that it is not working @Air... My Mac JDK environment is not able to connect any system environment variable to the locale... Only using props (JVM properties)...

Answer (score 31):

I had to control this in a script that ran on a machine with French locale, but a specific Java program had to run with en_US. As already pointed out, the following works:

```
java -Duser.language=en -Duser.country=US ...
```

Alternatively,

```
LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8 java ...
```

I prefer the latter.

Answer (score 19):

If you ever want to check what locale or character set java is using this is built into the JVM:

```
java -XshowSettings -version
```

and it will dump out loads of the settings it's using. This way you can check your `LANG` and `LC_*` values are getting picked up correctly.

Comment: Hmm, that gives me a "default locale", "default display locale" and "default format locale"... what the heck is the difference though?

Comment: Very nice trick! Thank you for sharing! It is useful when you have distroless container with no shell and only java command.

Answer (score 13):

You could call during init or whatever [Locale.setDefault()](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Locale.html#setDefault(java.util.Locale)) or -Duser.language=, -Duser.country=, and -Duser.variant= at the command line. [Here's something on Sun's site](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/javase/locale-140624.html#using).

Comment: The supported languages are listed at http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/locales-137662.html#translation

Answer (score 12):

For tools like `jarsigner` which is implemented in Java.

```
JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS=-Duser.language=en jarsigner
```

Comment: This environment works better, just add   export JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS=-Duser.language=en in your ~/.profile

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28327620/difference-between-java-options-java-tool-options-and-java-opts/

Comment: Finally, this is the option I want! java and javac does not seem to honour LANG and LC_ALL.

Answer (score 3):

You can change on the console:

```
$ export LANG=en_US.utf8
```

Comment: First, you need to write 'utf-8' instead 'utf8'. Second, only the encoding part works, but not the language part.

Answer (score 2):

If you are on Mac, simply using System Preferences -> Languages and dragging the language to test to top (before English) will make sure the next time you open the App, the right locale is tried!!

Answer (score 1):

On linux, create file in `/etc/default/locale` with the following contents

```
LANG=en.utf8
```

and then use the `source` command to export this variable by running

```
source /etc/default/locale
```

The source command sets the variable permanently.

Answer (score 0):

One way to control the locale settings is to set the java system properties user.language and user.region.