# Java Calendar - First day of week VS actual minimum

Tags: java, calendar

I was testing a piece of our date management framework which is supposed to reset some [Calendar](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/?java/util/Calendar.html) fields (using [actual minimum](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#getActualMinimum-int-)).

However, when [changing first day of week](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#setFirstDayOfWeek-int-), [Calendar](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/?java/util/Calendar.html) always return [SUNDAY](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#SUNDAY) (`1`) as [actual minimum](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#getActualMinimum-int-) for [day of weeks](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#DAY_OF_WEEK). Is it a bug ?

[MVCE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve):

```java
import java.util.*;

public class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.printf("Java specification: %s%n", System.getProperty("java.vm.specification.version"));
    System.out.printf("Java version: %s%n", System.getProperty("java.specification.version"));
    System.out.printf("VM version: %s%n", System.getProperty("java.vm.version"));

    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));

    int[] days = { 1, 5, 7 };
    for (int day : days) {
      cal.setTimeInMillis(0L);
      cal.setFirstDayOfWeek(day);
      System.out.printf("expected: %d, actual: %d%n", day, cal.getActualMinimum(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK));
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: It is not a bug. the day of the week depends on the Locale of your environment. en_US have the first day of the week set to Sunday. Duplicated: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/269486/how-to-specify-firstdayofweek-for-java-util-calendar-using-a-jvm-argument#answer-269538

Comment: I have changed first day of week ...

Comment: I think first day of week isn't the same as actual minimum. You have getFirstDayOfWeek() method for that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> You should use cal.getFirstDayOfWeek() instand of
>   cal.getActualMinimum(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK)

because 
cal.getActualMinimum(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK) will always return sunday look at the implementation of the  getActualMinimum(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK) in java source code

```
  public int getActualMinimum(int field) {
        if (field == DAY_OF_MONTH) {
            GregorianCalendar gc = getNormalizedCalendar();
            int year = gc.cdate.getNormalizedYear();
            if (year == gregorianCutoverYear || year == gregorianCutoverYearJulian) {
                long month1 = getFixedDateMonth1(gc.cdate, gc.calsys.getFixedDate(gc.cdate));
                BaseCalendar.Date d = getCalendarDate(month1);
                return d.getDayOfMonth();
            }
        }
        return getMinimum(field);
    }
```

And getMinimum is :-

```
   public int getMinimum(int field) {
        return MIN_VALUES[field];
    }
```

and MIN_VALUES array is defined as :-

```
 static final int MIN_VALUES[] = {
        BCE,            // ERA
        1,              // YEAR
        JANUARY,        // MONTH
        1,              // WEEK_OF_YEAR
        0,              // WEEK_OF_MONTH
        1,              // DAY_OF_MONTH
        1,              // DAY_OF_YEAR
        SUNDAY,         // DAY_OF_WEEK
        1,              // DAY_OF_WEEK_IN_MONTH
        AM,             // AM_PM
        0,              // HOUR
        0,              // HOUR_OF_DAY
        0,              // MINUTE
        0,              // SECOND
        0,              // MILLISECOND
        -13*ONE_HOUR,   // ZONE_OFFSET (UNIX compatibility)
        0               // DST_OFFSET
    };
```

Comment: Ok, i was thinking about minimum as value for rolling, not just the value bound you can have with get/set.

Answer (score 0):

The [Answer by K M PATEL](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29488862/642706) is correct.

Both the Question and the Answer use outmoded classes. The old date-time classes bundled with the earliest version of Java have been supplanted by the [java.time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

## Standard definition

The [`DayOfWeek`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/DayOfWeek.html) [enum](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html) defines a week according to the [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) standard, with [Monday](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/DayOfWeek.html#MONDAY) being 1 and [Sunday](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/DayOfWeek.html#SUNDAY) being 7.

You can ask a `DayOfWeek` object for this 1-7 number.

```
int dayOfWeekNumber = DayOfWeek.WEDNESDAY.getValue();
```

But do not pass this number around your code. Instead pass around `DayOfWeek` objects to enjoy the benefits of [type-safety](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_safety) and guaranteed valid values.

## Localized definition

For localized definitions of the day-of-week, week-of-month and week-of-year fields, use the [`WeekFields`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/temporal/WeekFields.html#dayOfWeek--) class.

```
WeekFields weekFields_US = WeekFields.of ( Locale.US );
DayOfWeek firstDayOfWeek = weekFields_US.getFirstDayOfWeek ();
```

Dump to console.

```
System.out.println ( "weekFields_US: " + weekFields_US + " | firstDayOfWeek: " + firstDayOfWeek );
```

> weekFields_US: WeekFields[SUNDAY,1] | firstDayOfWeek: SUNDAY

### Define your own week variation

I suggest sticking with specifying [`Locale`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Locale.html) objects to define the week. But if you insist, you can define your own variation of the week. Call [`WeekFields.of`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/temporal/WeekFields.html#of-java.time.DayOfWeek-int-) and specify (a) the first day of the week, and (b) the minimum number of days that defines the first week of the year or first week of month.

First, for comparison, get the day-of-week number using the standard ISO 8601 definition embodied in the [`IsoFields`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/temporal/IsoFields.html) class.

```
// Using standard IsoFields.
LocalDate localDate = LocalDate.of ( 2016 , 2 , 3 ); // Feb 3 2016 = Wednesday
DayOfWeek dow = DayOfWeek.from ( localDate );
int ordinalNumberDayOfWeek = dow.getValue ();
```

Dump to console.

```
System.out.println ( "localDate: " + localDate + " | dow: " + dow + " | ordinalNumberDayOfWeek: " + ordinalNumberDayOfWeek );
```

> localDate: 2016-02-03 | dow: WEDNESDAY | ordinalNumberDayOfWeek: 3

Now switch to defining our own [`WeekFields`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/temporal/WeekFields.html#of-java.time.DayOfWeek-int-) object, and again ask for the day-of-week number. Above we saw `3` because Feb 3 2016 is a Wednesday, so Monday-Tuesday-Wednesday renders a three. Below we see `4` because of Sunday-Monday-Tuesday-Wednesday.

```
// Define our own WeekFields to use in place of IsoFields.
WeekFields weekFields_SUNDAY_1 = WeekFields.of ( DayOfWeek.SUNDAY , 1 );
int ordinalNumberDayOfWeek_SundayBasedWeek = localDate.get ( weekFields_SUNDAY_1.dayOfWeek () );
```

Dump to console.

```
System.out.println ( "ordinalNumberDayOfWeek_SundayBasedWeek: " + ordinalNumberDayOfWeek_SundayBasedWeek );
```

> ordinalNumberDayOfWeek_SundayBasedWeek: 4

(example based on [this Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37796130/642706) by JodaStephen)

---

See similar Question, [java get week of year for given a date](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10278410/642706).

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

You may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. Use a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later. No need for strings, no need for `java.sql.*` classes. Hibernate 5 & JPA 2.2 support *java.time*.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), [**Java SE 10**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_10), [**Java SE 11**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_11), and later  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.

  - [**Java 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9) brought some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Most of the *java.time* functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android (26+) bundle implementations of the *java.time* classes.
  - For earlier Android (<26), a process known as [*API desugaring*](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support#library-desugaring) brings a [subset of the *java.time*](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support-table) functionality not originally built into Android.

    - If the desugaring does not offer what you need, the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) (mentioned above) to Android. See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).