# java.time.LocalDate.getDayOfWeek() to java.util.Calendar.get(DAY_OF_WEEK)

Tags: java, oracle, java-time, dayofweek

I am using the recent java.time package and in particular the [day of week getter](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDateTime.html#getDayOfWeek--) of LocalDate.

I get a nice [DayOfWeek](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/DayOfWeek.html) enum when calling `LocalDate.getDayOfWeek()`.

However, my code should be compatible with some older part of the application that uses the integer value of a Calendar weekday, i.e. obtained from the code `Calendar.get(DAY_OF_WEEK)`.

Obviously, in the DayOfWeek enum, [SUNDAY value is 7](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/DayOfWeek.html#SUNDAY), and in Calendar DAY_OF_WEEK field, [SUNDAY value is 1](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/constant-values.html#java.util.Calendar.SUNDAY).

So, what choices do I have to convert one into another? Should I convert the LocalDate in java.util.Date and then into a Calendar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`WeekFields`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/temporal/WeekFields.html) class exists for this purpose (used with [`LocalDate.get()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html#get-java.time.temporal.TemporalField-)):

```
int sundayBasedDow = date.get(WeekFields.SUNDAY_START.dayOfWeek());
```

Comment: doesn't really convert, does it?