# Globally set first day of week

Tags: android

I recently installed Android 13 via the October update. Among the changes is to set the first day of the week to Monday. Previously, on my device it was Sunday - my preferred option.

I know that I can specify the first day of week in the DatePicker class but I'd have to do that for every instance in every app (well over 30).

Q: Is there a way of setting that system wide? (Yes, I've looked!)

Comment: `DatePicker` seems to use [`android:firstDayOfWeek` to set that](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.styleable?hl=en#DatePicker_firstDayOfWeek), based on the Android 13 source code. Have you tried defining that in your theme?

Comment: I want a global solution - one that applies to all apps

Comment: Based on: https://stackoverflow.com/q/269486/295004 it would depend on what locale each app is using. I would double check the default system locale your device is set to.

Comment: Re "default system locale": that is the problem. I've searched the Setting but cannot find any such entry. I (very) vaguely remember such an entry but it doesn't seem to be available under Android 13. :(

Comment: "I want a global solution - one that applies to all apps" -- then how is your question related to programming?

Comment: Fair point - I guess this should have been posted elsewhere

Answer (score 0):

I got it fixed by switching my default language to English (United Kingdom).

The default is now Monday device-wide.