# How to parse pdf file that contain utf-8 character with java or C#

Tags: c#, java, parsing, pdf

I have a pdf file that contains utf-8 characters (İ,ğ,ı and arabic letter etc..). How to parse this file?
I use itext and pdfBox but I see "çekti¤i kå¤›da" instead of "çektiği kağıda". How can I resolve this ?

Comment: The main problem with UTF-8 and Java is that Java uses UTF-16, which is structured differently. I am not familiar with either of the tools you mentioned, but when parsing by hand, all you would have to look for is basically a 1 at the highest position of a character byte.

Comment: You mention iText. The current version of iText actually has become quite good at extracting text.Do you have any pdfs as benchmarks for the text extraction abilities you require?

Comment: Unfortunately recent versions of iText are GPL ...

Answer (score 2):

As no sample has yet been provided, I created arabic test data myself (well, actually I borrowed the code for creating the test data from some posts on the itext-questions mailing list) and a test which parses those data:

```
package itext.parsing;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.OutputStream;

import com.itextpdf.text.Document;
import com.itextpdf.text.DocumentException;
import com.itextpdf.text.Font;
import com.itextpdf.text.Paragraph;
import com.itextpdf.text.Phrase;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.BaseFont;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfPCell;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfPTable;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfReader;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfWriter;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.parser.PdfTextExtractor;

import junit.framework.TestCase;

public class TextExtractingArabic extends TestCase
{
    public void testExtractArabicChars() throws DocumentException, IOException
    {
        createTestFile(TEST_FILE);

        PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(TEST_FILE.toString());
        String text = PdfTextExtractor.getTextFromPage(reader, 1);
        for (char c: text.toCharArray())
        {
            int i = c<0 ? Integer.MAX_VALUE + c : c;
            System.out.print("\\u");
            System.out.print(Integer.toHexString(i));
        }
    }

    void createTestFile(File file) throws DocumentException, IOException
    {
        Document document = new Document();
        OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(file);
        PdfWriter.getInstance(document, os);
        document.open();

        BaseFont bfArialUni = BaseFont.createFont("C:\\Windows\\Fonts" + "\\ARIALUNI.TTF",
                                            BaseFont.IDENTITY_H, BaseFont.EMBEDDED);            
        Font fontArialUni = new Font(bfArialUni, 12f);
        Phrase myPhrase = new Phrase(LAWRENCE_OF_ARABIA, fontArialUni);

        PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(1);
        PdfPCell cell = new PdfPCell(new Paragraph(myPhrase));
        cell.setColspan(3);
        cell.setPaddingRight(15f);
        cell.setBorder(PdfPCell.NO_BORDER);
        cell.setRunDirection(PdfWriter.RUN_DIRECTION_RTL);
        table.addCell(cell);

        document.add(table);
        document.close();
        os.close();
    }

    final static File TEST_FILE = new File("arabic-test.pdf");
    final static String LAWRENCE_OF_ARABIA =
        "\u0644\u0648\u0631\u0627\u0646\u0633\u0627\u0644\u0639\u0631\u0628";
}
```

The String LAWRENCE_OF_ARABIA phonetically somewhat aproximates Lawrence of Arabia.

The output of the text is:

```
\ufe8f\ufeae\ufecc\ufedf\ufe8e\ufeb4\ufee7\ufe8d\ufead\ufeee\ufedf
```

While this is not identical to the input, a quick look into the unicode tables reveals that the input is from the Unicode Range "Arabic" and the output is from the Unicode Range "Arabic Presentation Forms-B". Additionally the output is left-to-right while the input is right-to-left.

I don't know Arabic myself and, thus, cannot say how accurate the output is, but the parsed characters definitively are from an appropriate Unicode range.

As far as can be told without access to the PDF the original poster works with, therefore, the problem does not seem to be the parsing but instead the proper use of the output of the parsers.

Comment: Note: This is a GPL version of iText!   Also mkl, you're working for itext & co - and you're recommending iText. That's fine... but you should play by the rules and add the usual disclaimer about your background to each of your answers which mentions iText.

Comment: @Ika Disclaimer: I do NOT work for iText & co. I'm merely using iText, am active on their community mailing list, and have helped reviewing iText in action, but that's it. And, furthermore, iText is AGPL, not merely GPL, but commercial licensing also is possible.

Comment: Yes, AGPL is more restrictive. thanks for that zoominfo link, I will have to look into that. That seems to have been created based on my reviewing of iText in action. My actual company is named in the references section. But i have not created that entry.

Answer (score 1):

As Bobrovsky mentions, it may look good, while the underlying encoding is not entirely correct. A glyhp that looks like an X in the PDF viewer may not be encoded internally as the character X. You can easily test this by copy-pasting the text from the Adobe PDF Reader to a text editor that supports the character set. If it copy-pastes OK, then extraction is possible, otherwise it is not (without taking manual measures such as a customized mapping).

Comment: We copy paste to word, we see '?' chracter instead of utf-8 chracters because  we donot have font file. how to access unicode mapping chracters that in pdf file with C#, java or any program?

Comment: @katsu Please do provide a sample file. Otherwise everything we can say here is pure guesswork. As mentioned before, I have had positive experiences with iText, and also other solution, both free and commercial, surely are also good for text extraction. But the PDF also must be properly encoded, and '?' characters are a bad sign. BTW, if you do not have a font file which can display those characters, why do you expect any text extraction program to properly output them?

Comment: Paste it to Word and use Arial Unicode. If it is still a '?', the encoding is wrong. It is indeed a good idea to provide the PDF so we can be sure. @mkl The fact that katsu sees a '?' does not necessarily mean that katsu uses the wrong font.

Comment: @FrankRem Right, the BTW on the font might better have been posted as a separate comment as it refers to the OP's "we donot have font file" only.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes PDFs are generated with different encodings specified in actual font bytes and PDF structures describing the font.

In such cases text gets displayed just fine but might not be properly extracted. I've seen this often for Western European languages.

To overcome the issue, [Docotic.Pdf library](https://bitmiracle.com/pdf-library/) automatically detects whether to prefer font file encoding.

Here is the article that shows [different PDF text extraction options](https://bitmiracle.com/pdf-library/pdf-text/extract).

Disclaimer: I work for the vendor of the library.

Answer (score 0):

Call the below function escape(String char) for each character. It will return you the UTF-8 character. This function is also from the PDFBox.

```
    private String escape(String chars)
{
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder(chars.length());
    for (int i = 0; i < chars.length(); i++)
    {
        char c = chars.charAt(i);
        // write non-ASCII as named entities
        if ((c < 32) || (c > 126))
        {
            int charAsInt = c;
            builder.append("&#").append(charAsInt).append(";");
        }
        else
        {
            switch (c)
            {
            case 34:
                builder.append("&quot;");
                break;
            case 38:
                builder.append("&amp;");
                break;
            case 60:
                builder.append("&lt;");
                break;
            case 62:
                builder.append("&gt;");
                break;
            default:
                builder.append(String.valueOf(c));
            }
        }
    }
    return builder.toString();
}
```

This is a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12577092/how-to-get-unicode-of-the-characters-from-pdf-using-java-and-pdfbox). Please have a look.