# listFiles(), isDirectory() method can not read unicoded data in java 1.4

Tags: java, unicode, lucene

I am using `Java 1.4` as my client requirement as well as `lucene-core-2.9.2.jar` and `lucene-demos-2.9.2.jar`. I am using `Ant` to build. It works fine for all directory except `Unicode` and `scandic char`.

When I try to listing using `listFiles()`, it lists all but `unicoded` data shows as block. When it wants to read the list using `isDirectory()`, it can not define those folder name for indexing which are other languages(containing `unicode` or `scandic char`).

How can i solve this problem for using unicoded data and scandic char?

If I use Java 6 or 7,It works well.So as per client need(Java 1.4), please don't tell me to use java 5,6 or 7. Give other valuable answers. As your  best understanding, I added my code below

```
public void addIntoIndex(File dir, IndexWriter indexWriter) {       
try {
    System.out.println("Now in addIntoIndex");
    File[] htmls = dir.listFiles();

    /** "Release_Notes" folder will be excluded for indexing */
    if(dir.getName().equals("Release_Notes") && this.searchOption.equals("systemHelp")) {
        System.out.println("'Release_Notes' folder will be excluded for indexing.");
        return;
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < htmls.length; i++){
        String htmlPath = htmls[i].getAbsolutePath();   

        if(htmls[i].isDirectory()) {
            addIntoIndex(new File(htmls[i].getAbsolutePath()), indexWriter);
        }

        if(htmlPath.endsWith(".html") || htmlPath.endsWith(".htm")){
            addDocument(htmlPath, indexWriter);
        }
    }

} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
}
```

Comment: Can you check you are at least using the latest version of 1.4 e.g. 1.4.2 update 30.  I would also try Java 5.0 or 6 or 7 to see if it fixes the problem, because it might not i.e. this will tell you if it is a bug which was fixed later or perhaps something else which is worng.

Comment: What systems does this affect? Linux/Windows/Both?

Comment: I am using windows 7.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At last my problem is solved. Actually I am indexing all my html files which are as

```
<html>
<head>..</head>
<body>...</body>
</html>
```

in this format.

After adding the following 2 lines in head section, this problem solved in my java 1.4.02 version.

```
<meta http-equiv=Content-Type content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="content-script-type" content="text/javascript; charset=UTF-8"/>
```

Special thanks to my project manager and  [Peter Lawrey](https://stackoverflow.com/users/57695/peter-lawrey) and [txtechhelp](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1152524/txtechhelp)

Answer (score 0):

Try this link that has some relevent answers for you:
https://forums.oracle.com/thread/1288135

You can try here as well for some other possibilities: [Setting java locale settings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64038/setting-java-locale-settings)

basically it sounds like you just need to ensure the right locale is configured to get the correct Unicode strings.

Comment: Actually I am searching data after indexing.If any folder name as tt.htm and it contains unicode, it can search all
unicode from tt.htm. If I have any folder name or file name with unicode, it cannot index this thats why it can not 
search the unicoded data.

Comment: How can I index the unicoded folder name or unicoded file name?