# How to resolve jenkins maven error 'Could not find main class'?

Tags: java, classnotfoundexception, jvm-arguments, mainclass

Jenkins fails running maven at all with

```
Parsing POMs
[workspace] $ java -Xmx1500m or -XX:MaxPermSize=250m -cp C:\dev\tools\jenkins\jenkins1.550\plugins\maven-plugin\WEB-INF\lib\maven3-agent-1.4.jar;C:\dev\tools\apache-maven-3.0.4\boot\plexus-classworlds-2.4.jar org.jvnet.hudson.maven3.agent.Maven3Main C:\dev\tools\apache-maven-3.0.4 C:\Windows\Temp\jetty-0.0.0.0-8585-jenkins.war--any-\webapp\WEB-INF\lib\remoting-2.33.jar C:\dev\tools\jenkins\jenkins1.550\plugins\maven-plugin\WEB-INF\lib\maven3-interceptor-1.4.jar C:\dev\tools\jenkins\jenkins1.550\plugins\maven-plugin\WEB-INF\lib\maven3-interceptor-commons-1.4.jar 55906
Fehler: Hauptklasse or konnte nicht gefunden oder geladen werden
ERROR: Failed to launch Maven. Exit code = 1
Finished: FAILURE
```

How can I change configuration to have english output? The translated error message is "Could not find or load main class".

I have read that `M2_HOME` needs to be set correctly, but I think that's the case:

```
echo %M2_HOME%
C:\dev\tools\apache-maven-3.0.4
```

I don't know if that is important for that error, but `JAVA_HOME` is set, too.

Is there something like a verbose mode for jenkins?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Hauptklasse or`:  this means MainClass with the name 'or' ...

The problem is with the second argument: `-Xmx1500m or -XX:MaxPermSize=250m`, the word `or` is interpreted as the name of the mainClass. Removing it should help you a bit further.

Comment: Ah, that is a copy and paste error, thank you. I thought this must be a translation error and didn't even think about being really in my manual jenkins maven configuration. Do you know why this output is german and how to change it to english?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/64038/setting-java-locale-settings gives a good hint