# How to set Locale to labels in Bar Chart?

Tags: jasper-reports, bar-chart, jfreechart

I am displaying a bar chart and trying to have the labels above bars displayed in **correct locale** (they are floats). I am developing in JasperSoft Studio 6.2.0. I set the global and/or the report (execution-time) locale to `en_US`, but the labels are still displayed in my Windows locale (`nl_NL`). I then set the label expression to

```
new DecimalFormat("#,##0.0##;(#,##0.0##-)").format($F{Hours})
```

but it's still in Windows locale. Only when I explicitly set the label expression to `en_US` locale:

```
NumberFormat.getInstance(Locale.US).format($F{Hours})
```

do I get the correct result. At other places (TextFields), setting the format pattern (e.g. to `"#,##0.0##;(#,##0.0##-)"`) leads to the correct locale being applied. In bar chart settings, there is no way to specify the pattern in the same fashion, that's why I am trying to do that in code.

Is this a bug or am I missing something?

Comment: I see I can use `NumberFormat.getInstance($P{REPORT_LOCALE}).format($F{Hours})`, but this doesn't let me set the pattern and is anyway far from ideal.

Comment: You can use $P{REPORT_FORMAT_FACTORY}.createNumberFormat("#,##0.0##;(#,##0.0##-)", $P{REPORT_LOCALE}).format($F{Hours})

This would create a fresh formatter on each call, which is obviously not ideal from a performance perspective.

Answer (score 2):

Yes I verified, jasper reports do not use its `$P{REPORT_LOCALE}` when generating the chart and I would almost consider it a bug. They use metods to generate the chart that does not support passing the Locale, but they could automatically generate customizers with correct locale.

To get desired `Locale` in chart label your options are.

Set **default locale** of the entire application.

```
Locale.setDefault(Locale.US);
```

see [Setting java locale settings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64038/setting-java-locale-settings) for other methods as passing parameter when launching.

If you only want to change the `Locale` of the label in your chart you need to create a [JRChartCustomizer](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/api/net/sf/jasperreports/engine/JRChartCustomizer.html)

**Example for BarChart**

```
public class MyLocaleCustomizer implements JRChartCustomizer{
    @Override
    public void customize(JFreeChart chart, JRChart jrchart) {
        CategoryPlot plot = (CategoryPlot) chart.getPlot();
        StandardCategoryItemLabelGenerator lg = new StandardCategoryItemLabelGenerator("{2}",NumberFormat.getNumberInstance(Locale.US));
        plot.getRenderer().setBaseItemLabelGenerator(lg);
    }
}
```

**In jrxml**

```
<barChart>
    <chart customizerClass="MyLocaleCustomizer">
        ..
    </chart>
    ..
</barChart>
```

Comment: A bug indeed, fixed at https://sourceforge.net/p/jasperreports/code/ci/8387491cbd8077639cfc8869953664af8ccc4da4/

Comment: data67 thanks. So how do I now get the locale in a customizer? *** 
  public class AssetsChartMod implements JRChartCustomizer {  ****


 public void customize(JFreeChart chart, JRChart jasperChart) {