# How to read Locale passed by Jasperreports in Chart Customizer?

Tags: java, jasper-reports, locale, jfreechart

(I am basing my question on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36383147/how-to-set-locale-to-labels-in-bar-chart/36385929#36385929) HARDCODED example from April 2016 and am seeking an updated, dynamic answer since the "bug" has been fixed - not having the locale available in the Customizer)

```
/* -Hardcoded example */
getNumberInstance(Locale.US)); //"Locale.US" is hardcoded rather than using the locale set in the report
```

**Goal**: Pass Locale set in jasper reports to chart and read with chart Customizer.

- How do I properly read the Report Locale now that the bug of it not being available has been [fixed (see here)](https://sourceforge.net/p/jasperreports/code/ci/8387491cbd8077639cfc8869953664af8ccc4da4/)?

**Problem**: In the Customizer Class (written in Java) this command does not contain anything: JRParameter.REPORT_LOCALE.

```
public class AssetsChartMod implements JRChartCustomizer {

    public void customize(JFreeChart chart, JRChart jasperChart) {

            /* ----> */
            System.out.println( JRParameter.REPORT_LOCALE ); // PRINTS NOTHING
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, we can't get report's parameters from *JRChart* object. This would be the easiest way to get *Locale* from parameters map.

But we can perform this trick:

1. Add property *locale* for chart at *jrxml* file.

The snippet of *jrxml* file with chart declaration:

```
<pie3DChart>
    <chart customizerClass="ru.alex.PieChartCustomizer" theme="aegean">
        <reportElement positionType="Float" x="0" y="0" width="100" height="100">
            <propertyExpression name="locale"><![CDATA[((java.util.Locale) ($P{REPORT_PARAMETERS_MAP}.get("REPORT_LOCALE"))).toString()]]></propertyExpression>
        </reportElement>
```

The property can be only of *String* type, this is why I performed cast at expression.

2. At *JRChartCustomizer* class I'm getting the property with help of 
   [*JRChart.getPropertiesMap()*](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/api/net/sf/jasperreports/engine/JRPropertiesHolder.html#getPropertiesMap()) method.

At my case the package name was *ru.alex*.

```
public class PieChartCustomizer implements JRChartCustomizer {

    private static final String LOCALE_PROPERTY = "locale"; // the same name as at jrxml file
    private static final Locale DEFAULT_LOCALE = Locale.ENGLISH;

    @Override
    public void customize(JFreeChart chart, JRChart jasperChart) {
        PiePlot pieChart = (PiePlot) chart.getPlot();
        JRPropertiesMap map = jasperChart.getPropertiesMap();

        Locale locale = DEFAULT_LOCALE; // this is default Locale if property was not set
        if (map != null && !map.isEmpty()) {
            if (!isNullOrEmpty(map.getProperty(LOCALE_PROPERTY))) {
                locale = Locale.forLanguageTag(map.getProperty(LOCALE_PROPERTY).replace("_", "-")); // here we have Locale passed via property 'locale'. Replacement applied: en_GB -> en-GB, for example
            }
        }

        // some actions 
    }

    private static boolean isNullOrEmpty(String string) {
        return string == null || string.isEmpty();
    }
}
```

Voila, we got report's locale at customizer.

Comment: Thank you Alex. What a nice example. One comment: ----locale = new Locale(map.getProperty(LOCALE_PROPERTY));---- does not actually create a usable locale element because the ----map.getProperty(LOCALE_PROPERTY)---- gives me "de_DE" (as example) but to create a new locale I need them split like ----new Locale("de", "DE")---- ...so to use it as a e.g. number formatter I have to split it first. -> ---- DecimalFormat formatter = (DecimalFormat) NumberFormat.getInstance(new Locale(part[0], part[1]));

Comment: Great. FYI ---- locale = Locale.forLanguageTag(map.getProperty(LOCALE_PROPERTY).replace("_", "-")); ---- does not compile for me (even though Eclipse does not show any errors). Had to use: ---- String[] parts = map.getProperty(LOCALE_PROPERTY).split("\_");
     locale = new Locale(parts[0], parts[1]);

Comment: Strange, works well for me. `Locale.forLanguageTag(String)` method was introduced at jdk7.  Which version of Java are you using?

Comment: Java V: 1.8.0_101. Jasper reports v6.4.1.