# Response assertion for the current date

Tags: jmeter, assertion

I have the following response:
-rw-r-----    1 www-data www-data 38269320 May 12 03:13 17003156.xml

And I want to create the response assertion that will check that there is current month and current date in the response (May 12). If I am using ${__time(MMM d,)} function for that, I am getting the following assertion error:

Assertion failure message: Test failed: text expected to contain /maijs 12

How is possible to set names of the months in English (like May) ?

If I am using ${__time(MMM d,)} function for that, I am getting name of the month in custom language.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[__time() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__time) will return month name in your current locale.

The options are in:

- Amend [`user.language` and `user.country` and `user.variant` system properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64038/setting-java-locale-settings) to the locale used by the system under test
- or switch to [__groovy() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__groovy) where you can specify which [Locale](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Locale.html) to use for returning the month name:

  ```
  ${__groovy(java.time.ZonedDateTime.now().getMonth().getDisplayName(java.time.format.TextStyle.FULL\,Locale.ENGLISH),)}
  ```

  [image]

More information on Groovy scripting in JMeter: [Apache Groovy: What Is Groovy Used For?](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-groovy)