# JMeter - xpath extractor returns umlaut wrong

Tags: xpath, jmeter

I am using xpath extractor in jmeter to extract links in a html response.
Some of the links includes umlauts! (I know that is bad style)

In the response of the http request the umlaut looks ok
a href="/ich-moechte/für-das-alter-vorsorgen"

But xpath creates the following variable with wrong representation of umlauts:
subLink_12=/ich-moechte/f%FCr-das-alter-vorsorgen

I compared the results with the Regular expression extractor which is delivering the correct result
subLinkold_46=/ich-moechte/f**ü**r-das-alter-vorsorgen

I also tried storing the http response in a variable and using the variable in the xpath extractor, but this gave the same result.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot reproduce your issue using latest [JMeter 5.5](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-5-5) and XPath Extractor

[image]

can it be the case your Java locale doesn't really support working with national characters? Check your `file.encoding` system property value using [Debug Sampler](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Debug_Sampler) and if it is not suitable for the umlauts switch it to the correct one (or even better use [UTF-8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8))

More information: [Setting java locale settings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64038/setting-java-locale-settings)

Using XPath for getting data from HTML might be not the best idea, have you considered switching to [CSS Selector Extractor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#CSS_Selector_Extractor) instead?

Comment: I have now also used the dummy sampler for the test (thanks!). 
And there was exactly one difference in your script.
I used the tidy option. When I turn it off, it shows the correct results!!!
In other words, when I turn on the tidy option, the xpath extractor has a problem with umlauts. I will also check CSS Selector Extractor.

Comment: With Tidy unfortunately you won't be able to amend the behavior without rebuilding JMeter from source as [output encoding is set to UTF-8](https://github.com/apache/jmeter/blob/rel/v5.5/src/core/src/main/java/org/apache/jmeter/util/XPathUtil.java#L254) while you need `windows-1252`. You can either [create an enhancement request in JMeter](https://github.com/apache/jmeter/issues) or switch to [JSR223 PostProcessor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PostProcessor) with [Groovy](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-groovy) if you really need XPath/GPath

Comment: In JSR223 PostProcessor with Groovy I added the following workaround:
String newLink = vars.get("subLink_" + i).replaceAll("%E4","ä").replaceAll("%F6","ö").replaceAll("%FC","ü").replaceAll("%C4","Ä").replaceAll("%D6","Ö").replaceAll("%DC","Ü").replaceAll("%DF","ß")
Is that the option you meant?